# Is there a way to have EditText on Image so that when clicked open Soft KeyBoard while ImageView wont change its position?

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity is having selected image from user and an editText to get user input. My problem is when editText clicked it opens softkeyboard that push Image upside to have bad user experience. I can resize or reduce image size but that I don't want. 
Will appreciate if somebody can provide ways to have Edittext displayed over Image so that when clicked open Soft Keyboard without changing image position. Can it be possible through RelativeLayout? Don't know if there could be other ways to get desired solution? Thanks in advance for your help!!!

My XML file

```
 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below ="@id/appbar"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/displayimage"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/newMessageContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newMessage"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/editlayout"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must prefer Framelayout as parent for Imageview and EditText.

Framelayout is designed to display a stack of child View controls. Multiple view controls can be added to this layout.

You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the **android:layout_gravity** attribute.

So you can avoid the problem caused by Softkeyboards as framelayout won't hold relative positionings.

Comment: Thanx for the response..Explored this too!!! but image also move up when softkeyboard open. Looking for a solution with Image remain fixed at its place  and can be zoomable as well while editText move up on the image when softkeyboard opened up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use image as a background for parent layout  and then put edittext inside that layout.
This procedure may be solved your problem.

Comment: Thanx for your response. This is easy way to do but then wont able to do anything on Image like zooming out or editing image..and hence not preferred this way. I want similar to what whatappp have when we post image.

Answer (score 0):

Try making  your Activity's windowSoftInputModeflag to `adjustPan` or `adjustNothing` in your AndroidMainfest.xml file inside your activity tag.

```
 <activity
       .....
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
    </activity>
```

Programatically:

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: With adjustNothing, softkeyboard is coming as expected but EditText still remain at its place. Believe EditText should be part of floating view?? What do u say..